# linQ query joining multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

How do i link 2 tables

- Events[ Event_ID , Hobby_Code]
- Hobbies[Hobby_Code]
- Members[Member_ID,Hobby_Code,Event_ID, Member_Email]

  so that when i sent an email to the member  the hobby code's of the Members and Events Table must be equal? I want to link Events and Members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from m in listOfMemebers
        join e in listOfEvents on m.Hobby_Code equals e.Hobby_Code
        select m;
```

This will select all the members that have an Hobby_Code that exists on some event